# How to add border in polygon plot?

Tags: highcharts, polygon

I am plotting polygon series using highcharts but i cannot add border to it. I tried to use plotOptions.series.borderWidth but no effect.

**Code:**

```
  $(function () {

    $('#container').highcharts({
        title: {
            text: 'Height vs Weight'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Polygon series in Highcharts'
        },
        xAxis: {
            gridLineWidth: 1,
            title: {
                enabled: true,
                text: 'Height (cm)'
            },
            startOnTick: true,
            endOnTick: true,
            showLastLabel: true
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Weight (kg)'
            }
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle'
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Target',
            type: 'polygon',
            data: [[153, 42], [149, 46], [149, 55], [152, 60], [159, 70], [170, 77], [180, 70],
                [180, 60], [173, 52], [166, 45]],
            color: Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0.5).get(),
            enableMouseTracking: false

        }],
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
            pointFormat: '{point.x} cm, {point.y} kg'
        }
    });
});
```

How can i add plot to  polygon series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set line-width to show a border around polygon using :

```
 plotOptions: {
        series: {
            lineWidth: 3 //whatever width you want
        }
    }
```

see the [Fiddle with your code here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/2ej5ng6p/)

if you want to set a different color in border of polygon use :

```
  plotOptions: {
        series: {
            lineWidth: 3,
            lineColor:'#ff9634' // whatever border color you want
        }
    }
```

see different border color on   [your code Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/2ej5ng6p/2/)